# How to change Makefile dependency file list based on target

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

My Makefile compiles a list of files but I would like to append new files depending on target.
The real makefile can be found here

https://github.com/fangq/mmc/blob/v1.7.9/src/Makefile#L4
https://github.com/fangq/mmc/blob/v1.7.9/commons/Makefile_common.mk#L192-L194

but to illustrate the problem, I have the below simplified snippet

```
OBJDIR=build
OBJSUFFIX=.o
BINARY=proj
FILES:=file1 file2

OBJS:= $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(FILES))
OBJS:= $(addsuffix $(OBJSUFFIX), $(OBJS))

opt: FILES+=file3   # append a file for a target
opt: OBJS:= $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(FILES))
opt: OBJS:= $(addsuffix $(OBJSUFFIX), $(OBJS))

##  Link  ##
all opt: $(BINARY)

##  Compile .c files  ##
$(OBJDIR)/%$(OBJSUFFIX): %.c
    @$(ECHO) Building $@
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(USERCCFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@  $<

$(BINARY): $(OBJS)
    @$(ECHO) Building $@
    # link file1.o file2.o         when make
    # link file1.o file2.o file3.o when make opt
```

my goal is when typing `make`, I want to compile and link `file1.o/file2.o`, but when typing "`make opt`", I want the makefile to compile `file1.o/file2.o` and `file3.o` instead.

but my above snippet can not achieve this. It can only change `OBJS` but it skips file3 in the compilation.

is there a fix for this?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is, delete file3.o when opt is not specified, then your link step is greatly simplified with a glob, as file3.o will not have been produced in the compile step.

Answer (score 1):

First, you've never declared that `opt` depends on `$(OBJS)` anywhere.

But more importantly, you cannot use target-specific variables to modify prerequisites.  The value of target specific variables is only available *within the recipe*.  See [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) where this is discussed in the second paragraph.

Luckily, you're just making this more complicated than it needs to be.  Instead of this:

```
opt: FILES+=file3   # append a file for a target
opt: OBJS:= $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(FILES))
opt: OBJS:= $(addsuffix $(OBJSUFFIX), $(OBJS))
```

all you have to do is write this:

```
opt: $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)/file3$(OBJSUFFIX)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I also thought this will trigger compiling `file3` (not necessarily linking `file3` unless I append `$OBJS`), but for some reason, even having this dependency, the compilation of file3 is not executed. not sure how to digest that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully.  Yes, this won't work.  I see you've accepted an answer which is fine.  I personally think that you will run into trouble with this model and I'd do it differently by writing out two different binaries.  If you keep things the way they are you should probably add `.PHONY: $(BINARY)` to ensure it's rebuilt every time.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `MAKECMDGOALS` has the targets given on the command line, you can use that in conditionals before all of the targets to conditionally set the variables the way you want.